# JaCoCo says 2 of 4 branches missed, which 2 branches are missed?

Tags: java, junit, code-coverage, jacoco

I am using JaCoCo for measuring branch coverage for my code. I am trying to find out which two branches are missed for following code?

```
 if (stmnt != null) {
      stmnt.close();
 }
```

I have tested this if clause for  `stmnt = null` and  `stmnt = jdbcConnection.prepareStatement("some-query")`  values. But I am not able to figure out what are two other test cases I need to test in order to make branch coverage  **100%**. 

In code coverage highlighting, there is a yellow dot which says:

> 2 of 4 branches missed.

Above code snippet is used in database related function as follows:

```
public void databaseMethod() {
    PrepareStatement stmnt = null;
    try {
       stmnt = connection.prepareStatement("<some-query>");
       //some operations
    } catch(Exception e) {
       //handle exception
    } finally {
      if (stmnt != null) {
         stmnt.close();
      }
    }
 }
```

I looked at other questions also but not able to identify missing test cases in this scenario. Any suggestions would be really helpful.

Comment: At a guess: your tests never throw an exception? The `finally` can be entered in two ways: after successfully `try`ing, and after an exception. If you've exercised only the happy paths, you've missed two cases: 1) `connection.prepareStatement` throws an exception (`stmt == null`), and 2) something throws an exception after that (`stmt != null`).  This is all conjecture though...

Comment: Also note, you might find it easier to get 100% coverage if you use [try with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Comment: Thank you @PaulHicks yes I am missed  1) connection.prepareStatement</code> throws an exception (`stmt == null`), and 2) something throws an exception after that (`stmt != null`). I added test case for 1st one but not able to find out how should I generate exception after (`stmt != null`) as I am using mockito for generating dummy class instances and even with real database connection this exception would be hard to generate.

Comment: Mockito makes it easy to generate exceptions. However... why? What is the value in achieving 100% code coverage for cases like this? The cost of maintaining this sort of coverage is high and the value is low. If there is an official reason (e.g. your boss knows nothing about testing and likes the sound of "100%", or your industry is stuck in the 1980s) why not write your code so that there are fewer branches? try-with-resources will help. AOP will help. A proper resource-managing container, or even a modern ORM, should look after all this stuff for you so you don't need to handle exceptions.